# How to update dynamic table rows in .net updatepanel?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, updatepanel

I have an updatepanel that stores a table.  The table dynamically generates rows of input elements for various property fields:

```
foreach (DataRow propertyRowToDraw in temporaryTableOfProperties.Rows)
    {
        // Create the property row
        TableRow propertyRow = new TableRow();

        // Create the first cell, and give it a value of the property ID, but don't display it
        TableCell propertyIDColumn = new TableCell();
        propertyIDColumn.Text = propertyRowToDraw["PropertyId"].ToString();
        propertyIDColumn.Visible = false;
        propertyRow.Cells.Add(propertyIDColumn);

        // Create the second cell and give it a value of the text, or prompt, for that property
        TableCell propertyNameColumn = new TableCell();
        propertyNameColumn.ID = "propertyName" + propertyRowToDraw["PropertyId"].ToString();
        propertyNameColumn.Text = propertyRowToDraw["Prompt"].ToString();
        propertyNameColumn.Width = Unit.Percentage(15);
        propertyRow.Cells.Add(propertyNameColumn);


        // Not sure what this does
        TableCell propertyHiddenValuesColumn = new TableCell();
        propertyHiddenValuesColumn.ID = "hiddenValues" + propertyRowToDraw["PropertyId"].ToString();
        propertyHiddenValuesColumn.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("display", "none");
        HiddenField hiddenPropertyDataType = new HiddenField();
        hiddenPropertyDataType.Value = propertyRowToDraw["DataType"].ToString();
        propertyHiddenValuesColumn.Controls.Add(hiddenPropertyDataType);
        propertyRow.Cells.Add(propertyHiddenValuesColumn);

        // Create a new cell for the property data type
        TableCell propertyDataTypeColumn = new TableCell();
        propertyDataTypeColumn.ID = "propertyDataType" + propertyRowToDraw["PropertyId"].ToString();

        // Create a dropdown list for the property data type for this cell
        DropDownList inquiryTypeSelection = new DropDownList();
        inquiryTypeSelection.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);

        // Cast it to the propertyDataType enum and do a switch to determine what items to add to the dropdown
        switch ((Altec.Framework.PropertyDataType)Convert.ToInt32(propertyRowToDraw["DataType"]))
        {
            case PropertyDataType.Date:
                inquiryTypeSelection.Items.Add(new ListItem("Exactly", "2"));
                inquiryTypeSelection.Items.Add(new ListItem("Greater Then", "3"));
                inquiryTypeSelection.Items.Add(new ListItem("Less Then", "4"));
                inquiryTypeSelection.Items.Add(new ListItem("Range", "5"));
                break;

            case PropertyDataType.Boolean:
                inquiryTypeSelection.Items.Add(new ListItem("Exactly", "2"));
                break;

            case PropertyDataType.Currency:
                inquiryTypeSelection.Items.Add(new ListItem("Any", "1"));
                inquiryTypeSelection.Items.Add(new ListItem("All", "0"));
                inquiryTypeSelection.Items.Add(new ListItem("Greater Then", "3"));
                inquiryTypeSelection.Items.Add(new ListItem("Less Then", "4"));
                inquiryTypeSelection.Items.Add(new ListItem("Range", "5"));
                break;

            case PropertyDataType.Double:
                inquiryTypeSelection.Items.Add(new ListItem("Any", "1"));
                inquiryTypeSelection.Items.Add(new ListItem("All", "0"));
                inquiryTypeSelection.Items.Add(new ListItem("Greater Then", "3"));
                inquiryTypeSelection.Items.Add(new ListItem("Less Then", "4"));
                inquiryTypeSelection.Items.Add(new ListItem("Range", "5"));
                break;

            case PropertyDataType.String:
                inquiryTypeSelection.Items.Add(new ListItem("Any", "1"));
                inquiryTypeSelection.Items.Add(new ListItem("All", "0"));
                break;
        }

        // Add the dropdown to the cell and then add the cell to the row
        propertyDataTypeColumn.Width = Unit.Percentage(15);
        propertyDataTypeColumn.Controls.Add(inquiryTypeSelection);
        propertyRow.Cells.Add(propertyDataTypeColumn);


        // Create the cell that will hold the input box
        propertyIDColumn = new TableCell();
        propertyIDColumn.ID = "propertyInputColumn" + propertyRowToDraw["PropertyId"].ToString();

        // Create the textbox input that will hold the search value for that property row
        TextBox propertyTextInput = new TextBox();
        propertyTextInput.ID = "propertyInputText" + propertyRowToDraw["PropertyId"].ToString();
        propertyIDColumn.Controls.Add(propertyTextInput);
        propertyTextInput.Width = Unit.Percentage(92);
        // Add it to the row
        propertyRow.Cells.Add(propertyIDColumn);

        // Add the row to the overall table
        docTypePropertiesTable.Rows.Add(propertyRow);


    }
```

How would I get the values input into those textboxes (propertyTextInput) on the server side through the updatepanel?  For some reason, the table does not show up in the viewstate when it posts back - even when I force viewstatemode = enabled.

I have to generate the rows dynamically because there are a variable number of rows based on other input elements on the page.

Fresh out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The thing with dynamically added controls is that that must be **readded** in every postback or they will not be accessible on the server side.

Are you adding the controls only once in !IsPostBack? if yes then remove the !IsPostBack check and readd the controls on every postback.

If that is not the case then please post the aspx code of the update panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a finite row of elements, say 10, you could create 10 blank rows in your table at design time and then populate them dynamically from the page.  If you need a dynamic number of rows, I believe that you will need to store your date in viewstate - I have the identical issue so should be able to post some sample code in a little while.